Access point as WiFi router/repeater not working
I have a Raspberry pi as a local weather station, with temperature/humidity sensors connected to over wifi. This works fine.
I also have an internet router at home and i wanted to make the raspberry pi an access point for the sensors as well as to be connected to the router (in order to get access to the internet on the raspberry pi).
So the setup should be (from my understanding):
                 wifi                         wifi uplink         wan
sensor1 <~.~.~.~.~> (ap@wlan0)RPi(wlan0) <.~.~.~.~.> router <───> INTERNET
            ╲             ╱               ╲
        (static IP    192.168.1.1        (dhcp
       192.168.1.20)                   from router)

So i followed the "♦ Setup wifi repeater" section, without bridge of this tutorial : Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge
I must have failed somewhere, as i'm now stuck. The raspberry is not connecting to my internet router (through wlan0) and seems to be emitting wifi for the sensors (through ap@wlan0) but on 169.254.139.31/16:

After a reboot, ap@wlan0 got "not associated", as wlan0.
Some details:

hostapd was already installed

step 2, here is my /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
interface=wlan0
ssid=ssid_of_router
hw_mode=g
channel=7
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=password_of_router
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP


Step 3, here is my /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="ssid_for_sensors"
    psk="password_for_sensors"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}


Step 4, here is my /etc/systemd/network/08-wifi.network
Name=wl*
[Network]
LLMNR=no
MulticastDNS=yes
DHCP=yes
#Adress=192.168.50.60/24
#Gateway=192.168.50.1
#DNS=84.200.69.80 1.1.1.1


Step 4, here is my /etc/systemd/network/12-ap.network
Name=ap@*
[Network]
LLMNR=no
MulticastDNS=yes
#IPMasquerade=yes
Address=192.168.1.1/24
DHCPServer=yes
[DHCPServer]
DNS=84.200.69.80 1.1.1.1




So my internet router address is 192.168.0.1 and the access point for sensors should be 192.168.1.1, so sensors with ip address 192.168.1.x can connect to it.
Where did i make something wrong ?
Feel free to ask for other details.
Thank you for your help !
François

You are attempting to run an 5 year old tutorial for an old OS, but have failed to specify Which Pi, What OS is installed (detail including version)  or even what network manager you are using. Raspberry Pi OS now uses Network Manager but if you switch to systemd-networkd it would work. NOTE I DO NOT recommend this as it is complex and there are simpler solutions.

I don't believe that the wifi interface can be both a client (associate to a root) and a root (accept associations from clients) at the same time. Perhaps it could be a repeater, but your requirements above dictate that it's routing at Layer3. You could configure the Pi to be a bridge, but it wouldn't route and you'd have to bridge two DIFFERENT interfaces, such as the wifi and wired interfaces. What you're asking is a no-go since you desire wifi on both sides.

Thank you for your answers.  You're right @Milliways, i didn't mention os and Pi i'm using !  I'm using Raspberry Pi 4 model B rev 1.5 with Raspbian 10 (buster).  The network manager used is hostapd, but i discovered that dhcpcd.service is also active.  Do you think systems-networkd would be the best solution, as you said there are simpler solutions ?  Thank you for your help !

hostapd is not a network manager and the tutorial is based on systemd-networkd so unless you use this you are wasting your time.  Most of Ingo's posts work, but are not all that easy to follow. He hasn't posted here for some time. I have used systemd-networkd and it is very flexible but configuring it is fiendishly difficult.

Note if you do decide to use systemd-networkd you might find https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117843/8697 easier to start.

Thank you for the tutorial. Do you think i can still use the RPi as a client to my internet router and as an access point for sensors that can connect to the RPi please ?

Or maybe i can use the router as the central point. At the end, i just want my sensors to send information to the RPi over wifi and RPi to be connected to the internet. The router must be the device for internet connexions and the RPi must be connected to the router wirelessly
